# How to edit the template of a node teaser that is sent in a newsletter email?

Tags: theming, emails

I have a content type for my newsletter, it has an entity reference field that displays the latest articles of my site in a teaser format.

I tried to edit the teaser display in my node.tpl.php like this:

```
<?php if ($teaser): ?>
    <!-- teaser template HTML here -->
  <?php else: ?>
    <!-- regular node view template HTML here -->
  <?php endif; ?>
```

in the website all is correct, what i put inside the if, is working but just in the website, but when i send the newsletter, the email arrives with something very different (something like a standard format), could you please tell me were can i edit the way my newsletter send the emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to change the teaser in the Manage Display tab under the appropriate content type. That will apply everywhere.

However if you have custom theme stuff you want to accomplish you'll have to make sure you're affecting the correct theme. It sounds like the e-mail generator may be using a different theme to send the e-mail?

A simple way to test for this is putting `<h1>HELLO</h1>` in a template that you think it's using.